# How can i control android mediaplayer?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to Android development in Java and Eclipse.

I am trying to develop an app which controls the built in Android media player. It should skip tracks when i press volume up/down.  How do I control the media player from code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the media button intents:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
synchronized (this) {
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
            sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,     KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
            sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
 }
```

Comment: Great code. A comment though on something that tripped me up: You HAVE TO fire the down and up, otherwise whatever is receiving your intent might not move properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a guide on how to use MediaPlayer here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html